# In what instance would I require parameters in python classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
x = 1
y = 1
class foo(x):
    def __init__(y):
        print x
        print y
test = foo(x)
```

This code obviously will not work. But in what instance would you pass a variable through the class itself, in this case x?

Comment: In a class statement, the "argument" to `ClassName` are the *classes from which to inherit*.

Comment: ooh, post that as an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance):

`class foo(x):` means that class `foo` inherits from parent class `x`.

When [creating an instance](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) of the class, the `__init__` method is called with parameters (of which the first one should always be `self`).